# Laravel, colon in all views and cli using artisan

Tags: laravel, response, command-line-interface

I have this weird thing in laravel project. In all output from laravel framework, I get this colon. It also happens in all views.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztLiB.png]

Comment: It's called a *colon* by the way...

Comment: yes, i forgot. thanks.

Comment: This to me looks like you have included a `print_r(':');` or `echo(':')` somewhere in the PHP. It may also be outside php blocks with a `:<?php` that was accidentally added when you opened a file. You will need to check through your code base. As it appears in the CLI and views, I would start by checking your `/bootstrap` files and work your way up from there. This will also prematurely send headers to the browser and cause you other headaches.

Comment: @DavidBarker I have tried searching in files with print_r and echo couldn't find any. But with ":<?php" worked like a charm. thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :-)